# Applying multiple functions to a pivot table (grouped) dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

I currently have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df:

 store  item  sales
0  1      1     10
1  1      2     20
2  2      1     10
3  3      2     20
4  4      3     10
5  3      4     15 
...
```

I wanted to view the total sales of each items for each store so I used pivot table to create this:

```
p_table = pd.pivot_table(df, index='store', values='sales', columns='item', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

which gives something like:

```
     sales
item   1  2  3  4
store  
 1     20 30 10 8
 2     10 14 12 13
 3     1  23 29 10
....
```

What I want to do now is apply some functions so that each total sales of items represents the percentage of the total sales for a particular store. For example, the value for item 1 at store1 would become:

```
1.    20/(20+30+10+8) * 100
```

I am struggling to do this for stacked dataframe. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.div.html) with `Series` created by `sum`:

```
print (p_table)
item      1     2     3     4
store                        
1      10.0  20.0   NaN   NaN
2      10.0   NaN   NaN   NaN
3       NaN  20.0   NaN  15.0
4       NaN   NaN  10.0   NaN

print (p_table.sum(axis=1))
store
1    30.0
2    10.0
3    35.0
4    10.0
dtype: float64

out = p_table.div(p_table.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (out)
item          1         2    3         4
store                                   
1      0.333333  0.666667  NaN       NaN
2      1.000000       NaN  NaN       NaN
3           NaN  0.571429  NaN  0.428571
4           NaN       NaN  1.0       NaN
```

Comment: @NZ_DJ Thanks, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer, if it suits you! :)